# Write Groovy code in .java file

Tags: java, groovy

I'm just new at Groovy and I'm following a simple tutorial.
I have this code:

```
class Example {
static void main(String[] args) {
  // Using a simple println statement to print output to the console
  println('Hello World');
}
}
```

but when I try it in my IDE, I got the error related to *println*.
I think that the Groovy syntax is not recognized.
So, is there a way to write groovy code in a .java file?

Comment: You write Groovy code in a Groovy file; why would you want it in a Java file?

Comment: Use a .groovy file instead. You can write Java code in it (not all Java code is valid Groovy code but most of it). Btw note you don't need parentheses and `;`, and also you don't need a class and a main method, you can just execute Groovy code as a script (class and main method are created implicitly).

Answer (score 4):

Simply: don't do that.

The file extension `.java` tells each and any reader (may that be a human reader or any kind of tooling):

> in here, **Java** code to be found!

Thus: when you put *anything* into that file that is **not** Java, you are simply asking for trouble! (I *have* seen people doing such things, and you won't believe how much **pain** that caused on other people working on the same project; so on behalf of all the people around you: *please bury this idea. Now!*)

You could look at this the other way round: Groovy is very close to Java, so if you think you have to "mix" things - see how far you get doing that within some groovy files!

Comment: *"Groovy is very close to Java"* Only if you use Java syntax! :)

Comment: @m0skit0 Sure. But the point is that you can put *most* java constructs into groovy files, and it will just work. The groovy interpreter can deal with a lot of java idioms; *javac* on the other hand doesn't support any groovy stuff ;-)

Comment: Absolutely. That's adopting Groovy is so easy, because the learning curve is very smooth :)

Comment: The problem is that my application is pure Java and I need to reflect some strings containing pure Java code. Is my approach wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what your real problem is. The statement `println('Hello World');` is **not** Java. Period. The only think you could make that work is by having A) a static import for java.lang.System.out.println() and B) by changing to " double quotes. The example you gave includes non-java elements, and an IDE that determines file content based on the file extension does not accept that. Long story short: maybe you rephrase your question to explain more carefully what you *actually* want to do.